# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "type" - how do i get the no. of times this exception is thrown

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am fetching the JSON response from a URL and this has property names misspelt. In this case, UnrecognizedPropertyException is thrown along with the propertyName. How do i keep track of the property name along with the count of the times the property is misspelt. Below is the piece of code:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
int counter = 0;
JsonContainer[] jc = null;
URL url = new URL("sample_url");
try {
  jc = objectMapper.readValue(url, JsonContainer[].class);
}
catch(UnrecognizedPropertyException e) {
    counter++;
    e.getPropertyName();    
}
```

Here the counter always return 1 though a property name is misspelt more than once. Also, how do i fetch the property name from the exception thrown

Comment: Of course the count is 1, because the parser throws exception when the problem first occurs, meaning that the **parsing is stopped** at that point. The remaining JSON text is not processed. Besides, you don't have a loop, so why would you think `counter++` would ever execute more than once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to skip unknown properties, but gather the names and counts of missing properties, you can supply your own implementation of [`DefaultDeserializationContext`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/deser/DefaultDeserializationContext.html), overriding the [`reportUnknownProperty(...)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationContext.html#reportUnknownProperty(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer)) method, e.g.

```
public final class ReportingDeserializationContext extends DefaultDeserializationContext {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ReportingDeserializationContext() {
        super(BeanDeserializerFactory.instance, null);
    }
    private ReportingDeserializationContext(ReportingDeserializationContext src, DeserializationConfig config, JsonParser jp, InjectableValues values) {
        super(src, config, jp, values);
    }
    private ReportingDeserializationContext(ReportingDeserializationContext src, DeserializerFactory factory) {
        super(src, factory);
    }
    @Override
    public DefaultDeserializationContext createInstance(DeserializationConfig config, JsonParser jp, InjectableValues values) {
        return new ReportingDeserializationContext(this, config, jp, values);
    }
    @Override
    public DefaultDeserializationContext with(DeserializerFactory factory) {
        return new ReportingDeserializationContext(this, factory);
    }

    @Override
    public void reportUnknownProperty(Object instanceOrClass, String fieldName, JsonDeserializer<?> deser) throws JsonMappingException {
        Class<?> clazz = (instanceOrClass instanceof Class ? (Class<?>) instanceOrClass : instanceOrClass.getClass());
        System.out.println("Unknown Property: " + clazz.getName() + "." + fieldName);
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
public class Test {
    public int a;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(null, null, new ReportingDeserializationContext());
        Test jc = objectMapper.readValue("{ \"a\": 10, \"b\": 11, \"c\": 12 }", Test.class);
        System.out.println(jc.a);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
Unknown Property: Test.b
Unknown Property: Test.c
10
```

I'll leave it to you to record and count the unknown properties, instead of just printing them, like the example above.